# How to allow only authenticated users to access a certain page via backend

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am liking firebase and what it offers for app development, still learning it..

So I was wondering how could I allow certain pages to be only accessible authenticated users via cloud funtions?

I know I can do it in the client side which is easy by putting this code just at the top of your main script

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    //do something
  } else {
   // redirect to login page
  }
});
```

It works fine, but what about on the backend?

I have tried it this way -- index.js for the cloud functions.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const firebase = require('firebase');

  const config = {
    // needed configs here 

  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    res.status(200).send("logged in")
  } else {
    res.status(200).send("not logged in")
  }
});

});
```

So I have configured the rewrite rules like this

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "/getstarted", "function": "api"
    } ]
  }
}
```

When I access /getstarted page it will check if authenticated if not just send unauthorized text / redirect to them /login page

So in my case after logging in the frontend, and I try to access /getstarted page it will still show not logged in

I must be doing something wrong..

Comment: [THIS](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint) and [THIS](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authenticated-json-api)  example shows a way but those codes look horror to me and I don't know how to implement to what I want

Comment: Both of those examples are for authenticating users requesting http functions via POST. You are trying to protect http files using GET. As answered below, this needs to be a frontend problem, not a backend one when using Firebase cloud code. Express + node generates your pages from templates, Firebase cloud code should do no such thing. It is a service used by your frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase cloud code runs on a remote server, not the clients web browser. The `firebase` variable in your cloud code has admin privileges by default, but will not be logged in as the same user as the client that makes a request to that piece of cloud code.

Also, `onAuthStateChanged` is an asynchronous function, that in practice will often return a null value on page load, quickly followed by returning an actual user once the page realizes a user was logged in. Because of its asynchronous nature, it is not fit for a single time (synchronous) check of if a user is logged in.

Instead, your first example with an asynchronous action on the client side is a good solution. It can result in "flashing" of a users only one to your clients, but that can be eliminated in many ways. One example would be to initially display a loading screen, and then to code

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // remove div containing loading screen
  } else {
    // redirect to login page 
  }
});
```

Comment: I see but it was possible when I was running my own nodejs with express I could even redirect

Comment: That is a different dev setup. Are you using any sort of frontend framework? Many modern SPA frameworks have preconditions for routes, and you could check if the user is authenticated for certain routes there.

Comment: I mean I could do what I want with my nodejs server running in localhost, if  firebase cloud functions is also running via nodejs, it seems we can't do what we can when running own nodejs in localhost server. I was thinking to use AngularJs for frontend framework.

Comment: See my answer to your comment above for why this problem differs with cloud code versus node + express

Comment: Yes, you can do what you do with your nodejs server just with Firebase and a frontend stack. No, the code will not be the same in every instance.

Comment: ok thanks for your help, I think I may move to Digital Ocean and buy VPS, that is better isn't it and I can do pretty much with what I can.

Comment: You can definitely run a Node server on such a VPS, best of luck to you.